# Does Azure MSI support VM Scale Sets?

Tags: azure, azure-managed-identity, azure-vm-scale-set

The question says it all. Does Azure MSI support VM Scale Sets? My team has a large number of Service Fabric clusters that run on VMSS and we'd like to take advantage of MSI there.

Answer (score 2):

MSI currently support VMSS. The UX flow is not released yet. However, you could use templates to deploy the VMSS using MSI: https://github.com/simongdavies/azuremsi

Answer (score 2):

There are also MSI templates for scale sets in the Azure Quickstart Templates (based on the ones mentioned above): https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vmss-msi-linux
https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vmss-msi-windows

:)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official documentation:

- [Configure managed identities for Azure resources on a virtual machine scale set using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/qs-configure-portal-windows-vmss)

VMSS supports both `system-assigned` and `user-assigned` managed identities.